# How to change the order in a YouTube playlist without drag and drop?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have a big list of songs in a YouTube playlist and I want to move the first video to the position 35. That involves a lot of drag and dropping, is there any way to do this faster by simply entering the position in the list where you want to move the video?

Answer (score 2):

The only options for changing the position of a video, as of now (March 2023), are:

- Move video to the **top** of the playlist
- Move video to the **bottom** of the playlist
- Drag and drop video to whatever position you want

So, sadly, no, you can't manually enter the position 35 to move the video. You can only drag and drop.